# Get documents by size of a nested field in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have documents in elastic with nested field
Here is a sample doc

```
"Not nestedKey": "Some value"
"sentencesSentiments": [
            {
              "sentence": "Good",
              "sentenceKeyword": "Good",
              "score": 0.8,
              "magnitude": 0.8
            }
          ]
"Another not nested key" :"Another value"
```

As you can see that the **sentencesSentiments** is the nested key, here is its mapping

```
 "sentencesSentiments": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "magnitude": {
                "type": "double",
                "store": true
              },
              "score": {
                "type": "double",
                "store": true
              },
              "sentence": {
                "type": "text",
                "store": true
              },
              "sentenceKeyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "store": true
              }
            }
          }
```

Now I need to get those documents where this "sentencesSentiments" is empty along with some other bool filters.
I have tried different queries but none of them is working, here are a few queries

```
GET indexName/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "sentencesSentiments",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "sentencesSentiments.sentenceKeyword"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


GET indexName/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
        "path": "sentencesSentiments",
        "filter": {
            "script": {
                "script" : {
                        "inline": "doc['sentencesSentiments'].values.length  > 0",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
            }
        }
    }
      }
    }
  }
}


GET indexname/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "inline": "doc['sentencesSentiments'].values.length  > 0",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried "values.size()" as well. Not able to figure out the exact syntax for this one.
**Note : I am using elastic version 5.5**

Comment: why not just test if the nested fields exists? like {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "sentencesSentiments",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "sentencesSentiments.magnitude"
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "sentencesSentiments.score"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: tried that as well, when i use the same in must clause i get the docs but what i need is those docs in which this list is empty, so i kept it in must_not clause and got zero hits, this is kind of unexpected behaviour that I am getting here

Comment: The querry you post search for no empty sentencesSentiments, you tried with must_not right?

Comment: yes tried with the must_not clause